# Emotion + Facepaint - use props instead of media queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stenciljs, css-in-js

I am using emotion on a project and would love to use the accompanying facepaint library like this:

```js
const mq = facepaint([
   this.layout === 'center',
   this.layout === 'left'
])
```

```js
css(mq({
   display: ['flex', 'grid'],
   flexDirection: 'column',
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   paddingLeft: constants.stylePaddingOuter,
   paddingRight: constants.stylePaddingOuter
}))
```

However, this is not changing the CSS depending on the set prop. As I can't find anything about it on the facepaint docs I am wondering if there is another way to accomplish the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Duh!

This was rather easy:

```js
const pq = (valueCenter, valueSide) => {
     return this.layout === 'center' ? valueCenter : this.layout === 'side' && valueSide
}
css({
     display: pq('block', 'grid'),
     gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr',
     visibility: 'visible',

     'h1, p': {
        textAlign: 'center'
      },

      p: {
        marginTop: 'var(--spx-space-xs)'
      }
})
```

pq stands for propquery ;)